# DART drawing on list of canvases in an iterated template

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I am displaying information about a list of items, which can optionally include a thumbnail.  If no thumbnail is present, a link is displayed to allow an image to be uploaded.

My question is: what is the best way to draw when needed on the canvases? (see below). I need to trigger a call to the code, and then also identify each canvas so that it gets the appropriate image.

I know it call all be done by creating the elements in code, but I would like to use the webui template mechanism if possible.

```html
      <template iterate="i in gItems.order">
        <template if="preItemDisplay(i) == true">
          <template if="gItemShowThumb == true">             
            <div template if="gItems.map[i].thumb == null">
              &nbsp;
              <span class="clickable" on-click="uploadItemImageClick(i)">
                Add image...
                </span>
              </div>  

            <canvas template if="gItems.map[i].thumb != null" width="80px" height="60px">
              </canvas>    <!-- ? How to draw on this canvas? -->

            </template>  
          </template>  
        </template>
```

Comment: Is this code inside a custom element?

Comment: Are you satisfied with Seth's answer below? If so, do you mind approving it?

Answer (score 1):

HTML Canvas is 100% code driven.

You can get the rendering context like such:

```dart
final CanvasElement canvas = query('canvas');
final CanvasRenderingContext2D cctx = canvas.context2d;
//
// drawing code here
//
```

There many samples all over the web discussing how to draw to canvas. There is very little difference between the canvas API in Dart and Javascript, so you should have good luck finding info on what you need.

**Update**. If you want to access a particular canvas, you can add a class or id to it.

```html
<canvas id='gameCanvas'></canvas>
```

```dart
final CanvasElement canvas = query('#gameCanvas');
```

```html
<canvas class='score_board'></canvas>
```

```dart
final CanvasElement canvas = query('.score_board');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it seems the point of my question is not clear to you (I will edit it a bit).  I know I need to draw on the canvas using code, the point is how to find all the canvases, and trigger the code to draw to them. query('canvas') won't work - which canvas?  And how would your code get called?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ID to your canvas element, then you can easily get a reference to it.

Try something like:

```
<canvas id="{{i.someIdentifierOnOrder}}" template ...
```

Then you can find the element with:

```
query('#the-id-of-the-element')
```

Comment: It seems Dart does not allow this. Please see "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038618/can-dart-bind-to-id-attribute". A solution to that aspects is to use data-* attributes. Secondly, I am unsure how the code would get called - it seems that what is needed is a pseudo event as in <template iterate="..." on-rendercomplete="drawOnTheCanvasesNow()"> ?